# MS Edge refreshes the page if an input's type changes from date to text.. a bug?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

If I set type of an input field to date, then focus, then set type back to text in MS Edge the browser refreshes. Is it a bug? Is there a way around it? Works fine in Chrome...

```
<input id="f1" type="text">
<button onClick="document.getElementById('f1').type='date'">1. date</button>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('f1').focus()">2. focus</button>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('f1').type='text'">3. text</button>
```

Try in MS Edge: https://jsfiddle.net/xb21ufqr/5/

Comment: I didn't see the second half of the question "Is there a way around it", I'll leave my previous answer as a comment: I don't see this behavior defined anywhere in the [HTML5 input type attribute spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-type) so *technically it isn't a bug, but a feature in Chrome*.

Comment: "date" and "text" both are valid values for attribute type, according to the spec. So not refreshing the page when setting an input field's type back and forth between these values is normal behaviour, not a feature in Chrome. MS Edge however refreshes the page. It also does it with a slight delay.. as if it tried to recover from some hidden internal exception.

Comment: Sorry, I must have lost part of my answer with that, when I said "behavior" I meant it as the ability to *change* the type (whether it's value is valid or not) on the fly, perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place but it's never explicitly stated about how it should happen so it's left to the implementation to handle it, and it seems to me that Edge's response to this was reflowing the entire page instead of changing the element's behavior

Comment: @PatrickBarr not allowing us to change an input's type would mean forcing us to use only `text` input for js created `<input>`. @OP, yes it's definitely a bug. The only two programmatic actions I can think of right now, that should cause a page refresh are `location.reload()` and `location.href = location.href` and ultimately `<meta http-equiv="refresh" ...>` but if it only happens in Edge, I think we can disregard this. For the workaround I hope that creating an new element would work, though I can't test right now.

Comment: I am able to change the type from date to text without the page refreshing, but it refreshes when I change it back from text to date. I am trying to create a JavaScript workaround for the fact that Edge does not allow keyboard input in input fields with type of date.